# Как закрыть окно при выполнении определенных условий?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qtimer, qmainwindow

При проверки на существования папки в нужной директории, должно закрыться вызываемое окно:

```
class Check(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MAIN):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        if not os.path.exists('C:/Documents/ValheimByLauncher/launcher.ini'):
            self.check()

    def check(self):
        self.hide()
        # self.close()
```

Но, ни `self.close()`, ни `self.hide()`, не работает. 
Ошибок в консоли нету.

[Гифка](https://ibb.co/pvqxNrL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы должны выполнять всякие действия, только после того как ваше окно сконструировано и показано. В вашем случае надо на миг отсрочить выполнение `self.check()`

```
import sys 
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets  


class Check(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): #, Ui_MAIN):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#        self.setupUi(self)

        if not os.path.exists('C:/Documents/ValheimByLauncher/launcher.ini'):
            print(111)
#            self.check()
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.check)     # !!!
            print(222)

    def check(self):
        print(333)
#        self.hide()
        self.close()


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Check()
    print(444)
    w.show()
    print(555)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.check), секунды указывать в миллисекундах?

Comment: @hoojpop да, в миллисекундах